# Displayed weather on lock screens

Tags: lock-screens, screen, weather

I am wondering how exactly do I get the weather to show up on my lock screen on my Nokia 400 5G

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Could you clarify whether your phone is [Nokia **G**400](https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_us/nokia-g-400/specs?sku=HQ5020Z379000) or [Nokia 400](https://www.gizmochina.com/2021/08/02/nokia-400-android-powered-feature-phone-resurface-hands-on-video-online/)? Meanwhile, could you also mention the Android version, in case it matters?